# Photos can't be copied from phone since iOS 17 upgrade

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos, airdrop

I'm trying to copy a photo from my iPhone and am unable to do so since Apple unilaterally upgraded my phone to iOS 17.1.1

Firstly, I can't copy any photos using AirDrop, WhatsApp, iMessage, Copy, or email.  When I try, I get the "Preparing" popup, which never makes any progress.

Secondly, my phone has silently stopped synchronising with iCloud.  So when I log in to iCloud I see all my photos right up until the moment of the upgrade.

The end result is that I have a photo on my phone which I am unable to get off my phone.

Comment: Tangentially related... Apple didn't unilaterally do anything, you have automatic updates turned on.  Settings >> General >> Software Update.  Turn that off if you don't want the phone to upgrade itself.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your phone to your Mac (assumption: you have a Mac) and using Image Capture to import your photos?